# I have bitcoin address but not private key

Tags: address, private-key, private-key-export

I am new on bitcoin concept. Few days ago I started working on it. I got my bitcoin address from https://freebitco.in while starting working through this. After few days I imported my bitcoin address in coinbase wallet but there alert showing that I need private key to use my funds.

Please help me to get my private key for present bitcoin address. I checked on https://freebitco.in but not found any option to get my private key. I am using my present bitcoin address on different faucets to earn free satoshis.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to recover private key?,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84215/i-need-to-recover-private-key)

Answer (score 0):

freebitco.in is a website used mostly for receive payments from faucets... Usually it's NOT recommended use it as a wallet so...

If you want to use Coinbase as wallet, the recomendation is send all your funds from freebitco.in to the wallet coinbase generates for you...

(until now I never used before Coinbase so... I can reccomend you to use blockchain.info as wallet because this has the option for export your recovery seed for store it in a very safe place...)