# Can I recover my own wallet from the public key?

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery, recover-private-key

I made a wallet years back. It has a good amount of Bitcoin then I wiped and sold my laptop. Now somehow I found my wallet address public key. Is it possible to get the private key somehow?

Comment: That can’t happen. Sorry for your loss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wallet gone and lost recovery phrase, how to get back my bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/64446/wallet-gone-and-lost-recovery-phrase-how-to-get-back-my-bitcoins) - see [answers to numerous similar questions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=lost+private+key)

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible.

The whole point of public key cryptography is that the public key can be shared with anybody, without compromising the private key.  If there were a way to recover the private key using the public key, this would all fall apart, and in particular Bitcoin would be horribly insecure.  This hasn't happened.

The public key could be used to determine how much Bitcoin is associated with that key, but it is no help at all in actually accessing those coins.  Sorry.